# POST or GET to call a REST action

Tags: rest

My app manages emails campaigns on which users can subscribe.
Those campaigns can be open or closed.

If I want to close a campaign I can do it like this :

```
PATCH /campaigns/<campaignId>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "status": "CLOSED"
}
```

But is it a correct REST approach to do this and set the status internally ?

```
POST /campaigns/<campaignId>/close
```

And can I replace it with a GET request instead since the body is gone ?

Same question to subscribe to a campaign

I would like to do this :

```
GET /campaigns/<campaignId>/subscribe/<userId>
```

But should it be a POST or GET request ?

Or should I do this instead ?

```
POST /campaigns/<campaignId>/subscribe
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "userId": <userId>
}
```

What is the most RESTful approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most RESTful approach ?

The RESTful approach is to make sure that your resources are consistent with the [uniform interface constraint](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5); which is to say that they should be consistent with the semantics defined by the [registered references](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) of each of the HTTP methods you use.

Recommended viewing: [REST In Practice](https://vimeo.com/41763224) (Jim Webber, 2011)

---

> can I replace it with a GET request instead since the body is gone ?

That is not a good choice.  The problem is that the semantics of GET are supposed to be essentially read only, and general purpose components are allowed to do useful things consistent with that assumption.

For example, you send to someone a copy of the url used to close the link, and their mail reader tries to pre-fetch the URL to reduce the latency observed by the human being.  Whoops, now your issue has been closed, and it's the fault of your implementation.  (See: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html )

```
POST /campaigns/<campaignId>/close
```

You can do this if you like; but doing so fails to leverage the [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons) that is built into HTTP.

Normally, you want messages that change the representation of a resource to target the resource itself.  So you might instead do

```
POST /campaigns/<campaignId>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "status": "CLOSED"
}
```

(Although you might need to have additional disambiguating information in the request body, if you have multiple different reasons for clients to want the current representation of the resource to change).

If you are trying to PATCH the representation of a resource, then ideally you would use a [patch document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-2) as the body of the request.

```
PATCH /campaigns/<campaignId>
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{
  "status": "CLOSED"
}
```

```
PATCH /campaigns/<campaignId>
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {"operation": "modify", "path": "/status", "value": "CLOSED"}
]
{
  "status": "CLOSED"
}
```

And if you really wanted to go all out, you would use the [Accept-Patch header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-3.1) to communicate to clients which types of patch documents you support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a more generic GET or POST to update a property then you have to have more information in the url or as a parameter in the url to tell your code that this is an update operation since your are not using the PATCH or other verb.

```
 POST /campaigns/<campaignId>/UpdateStatus
    (pass in body that has new status)

 GET /campaigns/<campaignId>/UpdateStatus?NewStatus=CLOSED
```

Something like above - REST Purists will say that this is not a good REST thing to do.